# /data/user directory is missing

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I created a database at `/data/user/0/name.vporton.purchases/databases/products.db` but in Android Studio folders structure for my virtual device there is no `/data/user` directory. What is this? Note that my code includes creating all parent directories.

Flutter (with sqlflite) code:

```dart
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
var path = join(databasesPath, 'products.db');
debugPrint("Database path: $path");

// Make sure the directory exists
try {
  await Directory(databasesPath).create(recursive: true);
} catch (_) {}
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to tell: `Android API 33 x86_64`. Maybe, bug in this image?

Comment: Oh,. it is apparently `Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image`.